# Please would like to know about Time period of pages opening in Internet mode within Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, group-policy, group

As Microsoft will be retiring IE from June 2022 ,suggested our customers  how to open sites in Edge  within Internet mode. For which we have deployed group policy  for it .
In *edge://settings/defaultBrowser* in Internet mode pages shows  "These pages will open in Internet Explorer mode for 30 days from the date you add the page. No pages have been added to the Internet Explorer mode list yet."

So my question is "Will the pages added to it only expire  within 30 days?"

"Do the group policy  that is linked to these listed sites also expire  within 30 days?"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Will the pages added to it only expire within 30 days?

The setting in your screenshot is called [IE mode local site list experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list#enable-the-local-site-list-experience). If you add IE mode sites through the setting, the IE mode pages will expire after 30 days.

> Do the group policy that is linked to these listed sites also expire within 30 days?

The IE mode sites set by group policies will not expire. It has nothing to do with the setting in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Rekha May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.